# Add imagemorph to rectangle

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I have a rectangle in smalltalk like this

```
cell := RectangleMorph new
extent: 70@70;
position: (500 + (aPositionWidth))@(100 + (aPositionHeight));
color: lastCellColor.
```

I'm trying to add an image to each rectangle like this:

```
  queen := ImageReadWriter formFromFileNamed: '9813.gif'.
    cell addMorph: queen.
    queen position: cell position.
```

It's not working how can I add an image?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 4):

`ImageReadWriter class>>formFromFileNamed:` returns a `Form` object. A form doesn't understand `#position:`. You need to convert it first to a morph. Try:

`queen := (ImageReadWriter formFromFileNamed: 'queen.jpg') asMorph.`